# Left merge in pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I have 2 tables that I want to merge using "left" option. Zent has 35928 rows, oil has 1371 rows after removing the duplicates. However, after implementing merge

```
oil_upd1 = pd.merge(zent, oil, on='Product/Service', how='left')
```

I am getting 35948 rows in oil_upd1 table. What could be the reason?

Comment: How did you remove the duplicates?

Comment: @mozway `oil = oil.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product/Service'])`.

Comment: It seems indeed unexpected. Any chance you can provide a reproducible dataset? Can you use `zent.reset_index()` on the left and give the output of `oil_upd1[oil_upd1['index'].duplicated(keep=False)]`?

Comment: Look like expected outcome to me. A left join includes all rows in the left dataframe, and matching rows in the right dataframe. It's expected that `len(oil_upd1) >= len(zent)`. Did you mean an inner join instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the test I used the following DataFrames (*zent* and *oil*):

```
  Product/Service  Amount
0              P1     100
1              P2     120
2              P3     140
3              P4     160
4              P5     180
5              P6     200
6              P7     220

  Product/Service  Xx
0              P2  Aa
1              P2  Bb
2              P3  Cc
3              P3  Dd
4              P5  Ee
```

For such data, the merge result is:

```
  Product/Service  Amount   Xx
0              P1     100  NaN
1              P2     120   Aa
2              P2     120   Bb
3              P3     140   Cc
4              P3     140   Dd
5              P4     160  NaN
6              P5     180   Ee
7              P6     200  NaN
8              P7     220  NaN
```

So, as you can see, for *Product/Service* = *P2* and *P3*:

- *oil* contains 2 rows,
- so the merge result for these *Product/Service* also contains 2 rows.

Since *zent* contains for these *Product/Service* only one row, the number of output rows can be greater than in the "left" source DataFrame.

Maybe you should drop duplicates from *oil* and then use it in your merge (a solution similar to the one advised in one of comments):

```
oil_upd = pd.merge(zent, oil.drop_duplicates('Product/Service'),
    on='Product/Service', how='left')
```